# How to get the source node from the dragover event

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, dom-events

From the event fired from dragover (using jQuery), how to find the source node (element being dragged)?

Data transfer doesn't seem possible per http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/editing.html#dragover

EDIT:
So after some additional research, it seems like Mozilla supports in through the [mozSourceNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DragDrop/DataTransfer#mozSourceNode) property. Any cross browser solutions?

Comment: You do have access to `dataTransfer.types`; so if you have access to the source element, you could use that to your advantage: http://jsfiddle.net/Hxb6t/ (drag both the span and the bare text).

Answer (score 0):

What about binding the source to the function and accessing it via this ?

```
object.addEventOrWhatever(function(){
  source = $(this);
}.bind(source));
```

Comment: What would this do? It's about HTML5's drag and drop functionality and getting the data being dragged.

Comment: Uh yeah... the function has to be able to accept various draggable elements (can't bind a specific element to it)

Comment: Ok, I see, I thought u wanted to drag only one object.
Have you tried to put a breakpoint and explore: 'this' and 'arguments' variables?

Comment: So right now I am using delegated events (jquery .on() ) to handle drag and drop. The event handler is given a jquery event object on which I dont seem to see a reference to the origina element

Comment: what about saving the source object ondrag ?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is very old, but wanted to offer a simple cross-browser solution I came up with for exactly this problem:

For the draggable element; on dragstart, add a class name (for example "dragging") to the element, and on dragend remove that class name.

This way, in whichever part of the code you need to, you can just get the element which is currently being dragged by that class name.